# Sublime + CodeSniffer problems

Tags: php, sublimetext2, wampserver, phpcodesniffer

I'm trying to configure my sublime with codesniffer but is show this error in console:

```
[Phpcs] C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16 -l -d display_errors=On X:\classes\activity.class.php
[Phpcs] cwd: C:\Users\mag
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
File ".\threading.py", line 484, in run
File ".\phpcs.py", line 396, in run
File ".\phpcs.py", line 128, in get_errors
File ".\phpcs.py", line 344, in execute
File ".\phpcs.py", line 347, in parse_report
File ".\phpcs.py", line 149, in shell_out
File ".\subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
File ".\subprocess.py", line 842, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 5] Acesso negado
```

My workstation configuration is:

Windows 7 32 bits,WampServer 2.4 (32 bits  & PHP 5.4),Sublime Text Version 2.0.2 Build 2221

And my phpcs.sublime-settings is configuration:

```
{
"show_debug": true,
"extensions_to_execute": ["php"],
"extensions_to_blacklist": [],
"phpcs_execute_on_save": true,
"phpcs_show_errors_on_save": true,
"phpcs_show_gutter_marks": true,
"phpcs_outline_for_errors": true,
"phpcs_show_errors_in_status": true,
"phpcs_show_quick_panel": true,
"phpcs_php_prefix_path": "C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.4.16\\php.exe",
"phpcs_commands_to_php_prefix": [],
"phpcs_sniffer_run": true,
"phpcs_command_on_save": true,
"phpcs_executable_path": "C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.4.16\\phpcs.bat",
"phpcs_additional_args": {
    "--standard": "PEAR",
    "-n": ""
},
"php_cs_fixer_on_save": false,
"php_cs_fixer_show_quick_panel": false,
"php_cs_fixer_executable_path": "",
"php_cs_fixer_additional_args": {
    "--level": "all"
},
"phpcs_linter_run": true,
"phpcs_linter_command_on_save": true,
"phpcs_php_path": "C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.4.16",
"phpcs_linter_regex": "(?P<message>.*) on line (?P<line>\\d+)"
}
```

Comment: What did you do to generate this error? What was the code you were working on? Does the error come back? What is the English translation of "Acesso negado"?

Comment: @MattDMo "Acesso Negado" = "Access Denied"

Comment: I'm getting the same error, using the same PHP version, same server (i.e. wamp), same sublime text version, even I run sublime as sysadmin. I installed Pear and CodeSniffer through pear as explained on its site. I tried use the configuration file above.